# Need help on how to approach an automatic fetch/ live React application connected to nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

my question is simple i think,
i have an app that fetches data from a backend server that i made,

now the app should be worked on by multiple people at the same time and they all should see live changes on the listed items in the app(if someone changes the list, everyone should see the change).

the app is quite small and simple
what is my best approach here? do i tell my fetching "useEffect" in react to fetch every couple of seconds?
or should i use socket.io?
and if socket.io is the best approach how would i properly implement this in react?
have useEffect depend on the socket call or...? wrap the fetch call in the socket function?

is there a better way than both?

im lacking experience to know

thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) is the best way to do this (Polling may work but is not the best way of doing it). [socket.io](https://socket.io) is a good tool when you want to code a frontend and a backend. You can [find an example of how to use it](https://socket.io/get-started/) on there site.

Comment: i started implementing socket.io but im failing to understand what login do i need to use in in order to fetch data on demand,
i have a useEffect in app.js that simply fetches data from the server
what approach do i take exactly to be able to say:
after someone does something - fetch the list again

and just basically call to fetch the list of items after some actions that people commit on the frontend

any idea?

Comment: @RPR If you [ follow this example](https://socket.io/get-started/chat) (also linked above) you will have your question answered. I suggestion starting from scratch and doing that example step by step.